# What is a good overview of options for access controls/permissions?

Tags: permissions, access-control

I'm in the process of designing the access control portion of a moderately complex application, but I feel like I'm re-discovering a lot of wheels.

Does there exist a good overview of the "access control" domain, including terminology, discussion of the tradeoffs of different schemes (RBAC, ACL, ???), how it interacts with business policy ("Alice can only access the coffee machine before 11:30"), and possibly implementation suggestions?

Sorry if this question is a bit vague. I'm still in the "I sort of know what I want to accomplish, but I don't know very much about the domain or terminology".

Comment: Perhaps you could give us more insight on your project.  Is it in Windows?  Linux?  MacOSX?  Networked?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm working on a browser-based application that will be to manage, schedule and report on advertising-related content. There will be different conceptual classes of user - content producers, content schedulers, managers (who want to see reports and the like) from different organizations, so you can approximate the kind of restrictions I'll be implementing.

Comment: Whatever you do, you should make sure to watch Zed Shaw tell you why the ACL is dead: http://vimeo.com/2723800

Comment: I was in the audience when that talk was given :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a security framework such as [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/); Spring Security in particular implements a lot of usual security requirements, has good documentation and I suspect well-engineered code (at least Sprinc Core has). You might be able to find a similar framework for your platform of choice, of course.